# Why is Angular FormControl holding checkbox value after unchecking?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm dynamically rendering a reactive form using code similar to the dynamic forms [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pebbxxgqobo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.html) that angular provides, but trying to implement a checkbox. When the checkbox value is left blank and the form is submitted, the cb control value is null, which is fine:

[image: Initial blank cb]

If I then check it, the value becomes what it's bound to in the template, in this case a static/hardcoded "true":

[image: cb checked]

So far, so good, but if I then uncheck the checkbox and resubmit, it still has the value of "true" - what?  (yes, I did click the submit button after unchecking the box - several times)

[image: cb holds value when unchecked]

Here is the template where the form is rendered:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
<label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

<div [ngSwitch]="question.kind">

  <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" 
    [formControlName]="question.key"
    [id]="question.key" 
    [type]="question.kind">

  <input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"
    [formControlName]="question.key"
    [id]="question.key"
    [type]="question.kind"
    [value]="true">
</div>
```

Comment: [value]="true" in your code ?

Comment: As I understand it, the "value" attribute should be sent only when the checkbox is checked.  The problem is that it is still being sent after the checkbox has been unchecked.